# Listing language skills causes error?

Tags: awesome-cv

I seem to have a problem writing the skills section, using `awesome-cv`.

```
\cvsection{Skills}
\cvskill{Something:}{S}
```

Causes error:

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
\cvskill #1#2-> \skilltypestyle {#1} &
                                       \skillsetstyle {#2} \\ 
l.2 \cvskill{Something:}{S}

I can't figure out why you would want to use a tab mark
here. If you just want an ampersand, the remedy is
simple: Just type `I\&' now. But if some right brace
up above has ended a previous alignment prematurely,
you're probably due for more error messages, and you
might try typing `S' now just to see what is salvageable.
```

The error seem to be caused by how the environment is defined,

```
}
% Define a line of cv information(skill)
% Usage: \cvskill{<type>}{<skillset>}
\newcommand*{\cvskill}[2]{
    \skilltypestyle{#1} & \skillsetstyle{#2} 
  \\
}
```

It thinks that the alignment tab character is place incorrectly, but it isn't so why is it causing the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `cvskills` environment, hence the alignment tab character is placed correctly.

```
\begin{cvskills}
\cvskill{Something:}{S}
\end{cvskills}
```

Btw: It's basically just a tabular (see [code](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/blob/master/awesome-cv.cls)):

```
\newenvironment{cvskills}{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r L{\textwidth * \real{0.9}}}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
}
```